# Asp.net 3.5 for Mvc 1.0 spellchecker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, spell-checking

i want a spell checker withoutexe,msi,control.
I want coding can please help me
Thanks 
raja

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery based spellcheckers.

- [jSpell](http://www.jspell.com/html-spell-checker.html?gclid=CNXVmdjZk6UCFate7AodUi8GNQ)
- [jQuery Spell checker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/)
- [jQuery Spell Checked plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellcheck)

And see [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1519923.aspx/1?Ajax%20html%20editor%20spell%20checker) on asp.net by jackyang